# Grails: A field that is populated in beforeInsert not being persisted but persisted if populated by beforeValidate

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, gorm-mongodb

I have a class `X` that extends `AbstractDomain` and has a field `createdByUser`. On `AbstractDomain` I have:

```
Class AbstractDomain { 

...
    def beforeInsert() {

       if(null != securityService) {

        User currentUser = securityService.getCurrentUser()

        if(null != currentUser){
            this.createdByUser = currentUser
        }
      }
}
```

but `createdByUser` is populated but never saved but if I change the `beforeInsert` to `beforeValidate` the field gets saved. What is causing this?

Update:

I'm using the `mongodb:3.0.3` plugin.

Comment: any constraints on `createdByUser`? any validation errors on `save()`?

Comment: @injecteer only `nullable: true`. If relevant, we are using mongodb.

Comment: is it the same with `beforeUpdate`?